# Less variables in selector with &

Tags: css, less

I want to use the & to attach a pseudo :not to the parent class however I don't know how to do this when using mixins and variable selectors.

```
.hideElement(@selector, @maxWidth) {
  @media (max-width: @maxWidth) {
    @{selector} {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}

.jp-sleek.jp-audio:not(.jp-state-no-volume-support) {
  .hideElement(~':not(.jp-state-full-screen) .jp-title-container', 580px);
}
```

The output I want is:

```
.jp-sleek.jp-audio:not(.jp-state-no-volume-support):not(.jp-state-full-screen) .jp-title-container {
  display: none;
}
```

The current output is (notice the space in the :not):

```
.jp-sleek.jp-audio:not(.jp-state-no-volume-support) :not(.jp-state-full-screen) .jp-title-container {
  display: none;
}
```

I know I need to use the & selector but this doesn't work:

`.hideElement(~&':not(.jp-state-full-screen) .jp-title-container', 580px);`

How do I do this?

Full code for context:

```
.jp-sleek.jp-video,
.jp-sleek.jp-audio.jp-state-no-volume-support {
  .hideElement(~'.jp-repeat', 400px);
  .hideElement(~':not(.jp-state-full-screen) .jp-title-container', 530px);
  .hideElement(~'.jp-download', 580px);
}

.jp-sleek.jp-audio:not(.jp-state-no-volume-support) {
  .hideElement(~'.jp-full-screen', 400px);
  .hideElement(~'.jp-repeat', 450px);
  .hideElement(~':not(.jp-state-full-screen) .jp-title-container', 580px);
  .hideElement(~'.jp-download', 630px);
}
```

Comment: No, neither special operator (like `&` or comma) has its special meaning in the interpolation. You could make the selector to cling conditionally via additional parameter of the mixin, but in this particular case I'd suggest you to make the whole thing up-side-down (by putting the mixin into a ruleset of interest) - [like this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/9063dba4225b488d36760c1e13aa62f1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` cannot be used as a parameter to a mixin or as part of the parameter to a mixin. When used in that way the `&` would have no special meaning. It wouldn't resolve to the parent selector and will just remain as `&`. Plus the below line is incorrect because the `~` must be followed by a `"`.

```
.hideElement(~&':not(.jp-state-full-screen) .jp-title-container', 580px);
```

I'd strongly urge you to have a look at the alternate method suggested by [seven-phases-max in his comment](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/9063dba4225b488d36760c1e13aa62f1). But a very simple solution to your problem while retaining your code-base as-is will be the following. Just take the `&:not(...)` part out, put it as its own block and then invoke  `.hideElement` mixin within this block with just the other part of the selector (the child selector) as input.

```
.jp-sleek.jp-video,
.jp-sleek.jp-audio.jp-state-no-volume-support {
  .hideElement(~'.jp-repeat', 400px);
  &:not(.jp-state-full-screen){ /* take the not part out and put it as a block */
    .hideElement(~'.jp-title-container', 530px);
  }
  .hideElement(~'.jp-download', 580px);
}

.jp-sleek.jp-audio:not(.jp-state-no-volume-support) {
  .hideElement(~'.jp-full-screen', 400px);
  .hideElement(~'.jp-repeat', 450px);
  &:not(.jp-state-full-screen) { /* take the not part out and put it as a block */
    .hideElement(~'.jp-title-container', 580px);
  }
  .hideElement(~'.jp-download', 630px);
}
```